# How to show a placeholder instead of an equation?

Tags: equations, formatting

I am looking for functionality similar to the endfloat package but for equations. Instead of displaying an equation I would like to display a placeholder such as

```
[equation 1 here]
```

Does anyone know of such a package?

Comment: I don't understand what prevents you from writing precisely that? maybe with `boxed{}`? I've had a hard combustion exam today so maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: I basically want to have a switch to turn off all equations but still have the automatic numbering. But also have the options to turn them on as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for the standard `equation` environment, but not for other math environments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\let\oldequation\equation
\let\oldendequation\endequation
\renewenvironment{equation}
  {\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\oldequation}
  {\oldendequation\egroup\[\hbox{[Equation \theequation\ here]}\]}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I can't think of any application.

Comment: This example works! And it is exactly what I need! My application is that I am writing a journal article, and my colleges can only work in word. The conversion to word from pdf goes much smoother when there is no math in the document but I still need to reference the equations. I also needed to be able to turn it off for the final version when I submit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but you want to add reminder in the document to go back and actually add the equation there, then the `todonotes` package would be useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\todo[inline]{equation 1 here}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would work except the numbering is not automatic.